# Copying a SQL database under a new name to same server

Tags: sql-server, backup, ssms, rename

I am trying to create a copy of a SQL Server 2008 database under a new name on the same server.

I have physical access to the machine. I have tried to create a full backup and then restore that backup under a new name and I get an error from SSMS that "The backup set holds a backup for a database other than the selected database."

I have also tried doing a `restore from database` rather than `restore from file` and that did not work either.

What is the best way of making a full backup of a database and restoring the database with a new name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh! The name of the database that you intend the copy to be must not exist.

I got it to work now [facepalm]

Answer (score 0):

When making that full backup, select to "Overwrite" your old backup or save it under a different name altogether.

Or you can use T-SQL:

RESTORE DATABASE YourDatabase
FROM DISK = 'C:\YourDatabase.bak'
WITH REPLACE